# Best way to upload Chatter file

Tags: rest-api, chatter, feeditem, files

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm) document,

> In version 36.0 and later, you can’t create a feed post and upload a binary file in the same request. Upload files to Salesforce first, and then use the file IDs to attach one or more files to a feed post.

So now you have to upload the file first, then reference the file Id when creating a feed element from the REST API

```
{
"body":{
  "messageSegments":[
     {
        "type":"Text",
        "text":"Please take a look at these files."
     }
  ]
},
"capabilities":{
  "files":{
     "items": [
        {"id": "069D00000001IOh"},
        {"id": "069D00000002IOg"}
     ]
  }
},
"subjectId":"me",
"feedElementType":"FeedItem"
}
```

My question is, what is the best practice for uploading files to Salesforce? The only way I can see to just upload a file is using this resource:

`/services/data/v40.0/connect/files/users/me`

However, if I upload it to "me" will everyone who has access to the record have access to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is uploaded to `me` then it is by default `privately` shared.

You need to open up file access via sharing.

Refer [Who Can See My File?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=collab_files_settings_perms.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0&language=en_US)

[image: file sharing]

Comment: How do you this programmatically via the REST API?